# Minecraft PS4 constant errors

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I recently downloaded the city life map on Minecraft on my PlayStation four, an ever since I have, every time I use the game it lets me play a bit, then says

> An error has occured In the following application:
> (CE-34878-0)
> Minecraft

Does anyone know what this error is?

Answer (score 1):

CE-34878-0 is the general error on Playstation 4 apps. It means the application did something it wasn't supposed to so the Playstation OS had to stop the program.

Playing on PS4 I've encountered quite a few of these errors as well. PS4 is the most recent bedrock port so it doesn't surprise me that the game is crashy. Hopefully in a few updates the game will act more stably.

Comment: Thanks! ;) That helps. I'll wait a bit before I play again

Comment: No problem. It's still possible to play the legacy PS4 edition in the mean-time via the "Edititions" button on the title screen.